# how Nginx block uri?

Tags: nginx

I set my nginx with Angular webpack (eg. www).

I use nginx 1.2.3.4 to proxy another VM 123.4.5.6;

My nginx config is very simple.

```
eg. nginx's IP = 1.2.3.4;
eg. another VM's IP = 123.4.5.6;
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost
    location / {
        proxy_pass 123.4.5.6; 
    }
}
```

And there are a lot sub pages like pageA,pageB in www;
So I can type 1.2.3.4 to see the first page. 
And I can type 1.2.3.4/pageA to see the A page.

Here is my question 
How can I block uri which is not included in our page;

I try stupid way like

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost
    location / {
        if($uri != "pageA") {
            return 404;
        }
        proxy_pass 123.4.5.6; 
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to accept multiple uri 
I tried the below way but it doesn't work.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost
    location / {
        if($uri != "pageA" || $uri != "pageB") {
            return 404;
        }
        proxy_pass 123.4.5.6; 
    }
}
```

Also I want to know some better way to solve this problem.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Since you're using angular, why don't you let it handle the routing?

Comment: oh~ I will try it thanks~~~.